# Going back to admin party

Tags: couchdb

I would like to bring my CouchDB instance back to admin party. It is running on localhost, so it is not a security concern. I don't want to reinstall it because I have some databases up and running I'd like to keep.

I tried commenting out the admin user in my `local.ini`:

```
[admins]
#admin = -hashed-xxxxxx
```

I also deleted all the non-design documents from my `_users` database.

The main goal I have for wanting to go back to the admin party is to be able to create databases without authentication.

What can I do to go back to the admin party? Alternatively how can I setup my instance such that an anonymous user can create and delete databases?

Comment: Have you restarted the database after changing `local.ini`?

Comment: Yes, I stopped and started couch.

Comment: Just to be clear: in order to get back to admin party, you edit the local.ini (/etc/couchdb/local.ini on Ubuntu) and comment out all [admins] entries using ; or just delete all lines.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`#` is not a valid comment in this configuration format, Use `;` instead.

If you try to login as `#admin` (rather than just `admin`) it will let you, if you give the right password. So, either remove the line altogether, or prefix it with `;`.

Comment: I also had to comment out the lines under the `couch_httpd_auth` section in local.ini

Answer (score 9):

You can also do that through CouchDB Web UI.

1. Go to the configuration panel (`http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/config.html` in CouchDB 1.x or `http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/#_config` in CouchDB 2.x).
2. In the `admin` section, delete all rows.
3. Relax: this is "admin party" again.

Comment: Thanks! And don't forget to log in first :).